# I cannot get Input System (unity) to function properly function with my code, I don't know how to fix this

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging

In Unity, after setting up the Input System following [Brackeys' tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-3S73MaDP8&t=483s), Unity comes up with this error.

> Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(31,18): error CS1061: 'PlayerController' does not contain a definition for 'Gameplay' and no accessible extension method 'Gameplay' accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't fully know what the problem is, or how to fix it. It is repeated in lines 42 and 47.
Here is my code:

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerController controls;
    public Vector3 jump;
    public float jumpForce = 2.0f;

    public bool isGrounded;
    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        controls = new PlayerController();

        controls.Gameplay.Jump.performed += ctx => Jump(); // <-- error here
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Gameplay.Enable(); // <-- error here
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Gameplay.Disable(); // <-- error here
    }
}
```

In my game, I am trying to get my character to jump. Here's the game:
[my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMKKm.png)

Here's my Input System Stuff:
[Input System Stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWsqu.png)

I have no idea what to do, please help!

Comment: You're writing the class `PlayerController`, which is the type you've declared `objects` to be. Your code's `PlayerController` does not implement anything for `Gameplay` that you're attempting to call methods of in each place you're getting the error.

Comment: I suspect there is another type called `PlayerController` in a different namespace you were intending to use but since you called your own class the same name it is now confusing them

Comment: Also since your `PlayerController` is of type `MonoBehaviour` it is not allowed (and makes no sense) to use `new PlayerController()` since a component can't exist without being attached to a GameObject ...